# PHP unset array value based on key

Tags: php, arrays

I have multidimensional array as follows,

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [data] => 
        [id] => 0000
        [name] => Swirl
        [categories] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 0001
                        [name] => Whirl
                        [products] => Array 
                           (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 0002
                                        [filename] => 1.jpg
                                     )
                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 0003
                                        [filename] => 2.jpg
                                     )
                            )
                     )
             )
      )
```

I have used the following function to find keys.

```
function find_parent($array, $needle, $parent = null) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $pass = $parent;
            if (is_string($key)) {
                $pass = $key;
            }
            $found = find_parent($value, $needle, $pass);
            if ($found !== false) {
                return $found;
            }
        } else if ($key === $needle) {
            return $parent;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

$parentkey = find_parent($array, 'id');
```

Now i need to unset the products array and replace it with another array.

how to do this.please help.

Thanks,
sarnitha

Comment: There is no need to unset before replacing. Just replace.

Comment: how to loop thru array keys and replace array.please give me some idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive function over an array:

```
function replaceInArray(array &$arr, $needleKey, array $replacement) {
  foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
    if ($k === $needleKey) {
        $arr[$k] = $replacement;
    } else {
        if (is_array($v)) {
            replaceInArray($arr[$k], $needleKey, $replacement);
        }
    }
  }
}

replaceInArray($sourceArr, 'products', ['id' => '0004', 'filename' => 'new.jpg']);

function replaceInArrayWithKey(array &$arr, $needleKey, array $replacementArray, $replacementKey) {
  foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
    if ($k === $needleKey) {
        $arr[$replacementKey] = $replacementArray;
        unset($arr[$k]);
    } else {
        if (is_array($v)) {
            replaceInArrayWithKey($arr[$k], $needleKey, $replacementArray, $replacementKey);
        }
    }
  }
}

replaceInArrayWithKey($sourceArray, 'products', ['id' => '0004', 'filename' => 'new.jpg'], 'products_new');
```

You can also try using a built-in recursive iterator - https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php